# Failed to load CSS in HTTPS protocol

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I created a blog using Laravel, and I am having a weird issue. I pushed my project to Heroku (`nepshare.herokuapp.com`). When I visit this URL my site loads but with no CSS and I refreshed every time to make it load but failed. 
Finally, I changed the `https://nepshare.herokuapp.com` URL to `http://nepshare.herokuapp.com` (changed from HTTPS to HTTP) then everything works just fine.css are only loaded in HTTP. How to render all CSS in HTTPS protocol? The following is my main layout code:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

@include('inc.navbar')
<div class="container">
    @include('inc.messages')
    @yield('content')
</div>

<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('article-ckeditor');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got more details on how you include you CSS?

Comment: just use ```//``` instead of ```http://``` when you include a URL ?

Comment: @BookOfZeus i have updated the post, as i have included css using that above process

Comment: where is the ```asset``` method defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .env file define new property,

```
REDIRECT_HTTPS = true
```

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` add this,

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
            $url->formatScheme('https');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if(env('REDIRECT_HTTPS')) {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use,

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Or you can use `secure_asset()` helper function but `secure_asset()` method only use https: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-secure-asset

Comment: when i tried 1st method my project failed to push in heroku idk why and i tried second method after reverting changes and everything works jst fine thankyou

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `secure_asset` helper function instead of asset to resolve this issue. The secure_asset function generates a URL for an asset using HTTPS.

```
$url = secure_asset('img/photo.jpg');
```